# PHP JSON GET showing correctly on webpage, but not in php

Tags: php, json

my code:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $url = "http://80.211.192.133:8117/stats";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $obj = json_decode($json);

    $error = json_last_error();

    var_dump($error);
?>
```

I am getting error:

```
code 5 - Malformed UTF-8 characters when encoding callback response
```

but when you open the link from `$url` variable, it is showing correct data.

can someone help me with that?

Comment: what does `echo $json` show?

Comment: @KamrulKhan   mR�n�0�cϪAI��:
�CS�ࢇ��\YD(� ������I�'iV3���+Hg[}��
g�c����MN���m��`���10Hh�7hզ^��#ܒWbA����;�V/� �ǭ��従�����'�N�΋���Un��$B�8���-QѠ��YzH \��3?~�$��BTΊ�Qf��o��r����V�� ��s^�v���ۜ${m��ң���c�Qk��&W��Y���s�h�|>��ɂB�����+���#�b��1vKh�S�+�(�����Ul:0-,�(�� ��2�}w��!g
��l��s@z����֟Ļ��G��ʒ̓Y�����l�7�Y��i��ڭIxU9Sz�џɧHI��9���4G�?�3&J�J�J�:�j֢� �e�*�ڪHU^�q̎5O��+�3��_

Comment: I sincerely doubt this is a charset issue. I believe it is more likely due to the fact that the source is delivering the content using `Content-Encoding: deflate`. It might be a duplicate of something here, but certainly not the one currently indicated.

Comment: i agree, this is not a duplicate at all. i tried playing with the deflate in PHP, but never done that much. sorry, no "help" time left, but does not seem like a charset issue at all.

Comment: ok, actualy, i found it : <?php
$url = "http://80.211.192.133:8117/stats";

$data = file_get_contents($url);

$data = gzinflate( $data );
  
var_dump($data);

Comment: @blueweb   GREAT - That worked, thanks a lot!  Problem solved :)

Comment: @Machavity this is NOT a duplicate question.

Comment: @blueweb, you are correct. vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue comes from the server compressing your data. `gzinflate` will help you out here:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$url = "http://80.211.192.133:8117/stats";
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$data = gzinflate( $data ); 
$obj = json_decode($data,true);
```

In all fairness, @Octopus also spotted the important part.

Comment: It is unfortunate that PHP doesn't automatically do this when it sees the header. There is no guarantee that the source will always use the same `Content-Encoding`. To be safe your PHP should check for the presence of the header and its value.